# How to replicate column-names, split them at delimiter '/', into multiple column-names, in R?

Tags: r, regex, matrix, string-parsing

I have this matrix (it's big in size) "mymat". I need to replicate the columns that have "/" in their column name matching at "/" and make a "resmatrix". How can I get this done in R?

mymat

```
 a   b   IID:WE:G12D/V    GH:SQ:p.R172W/G   c
 1   3               4                  2   4
22   4               2                  2   4
 2   3               2                  2   4
```

resmatrix

```
 a   b   IID:WE:G12D   IID:WE:G12V    GH:SQ:p.R172W    GH:SQ:p.R172G   c
 1   3             4             4                2                2   4
22   4             2             2                2                2   4
 2   3             2             2                2                2   4
```

Answer (score 3):

Find out which columns have the "/" and replicate them, then rename. To calculate the new names, just split on `/` and replace the last letter for the second name.

```
# which columns have '/' in them?
which.slash <- grep('/', names(mymat), value=T)
new.names <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(which.slash, '/'),
       function (bits) {
         # bits[1] is e.g. IID:WE:G12D and bits[2] is the V
         # take bits[1] and replace the last letter for the second colname
         c(bits[1], sub('.$', bits[2], bits[1]))
       }))

# make resmat by copying the appropriate columns
resmat <- cbind(mymat, mymat[, which.slash])
# order the columns to make sure the names replace properly
resmat <- resmat[, order(names(resmat))]
# put the new names in
names(resmat)[grep('/', names(resmat))] <- sort(new.names)
```

`resmat` looks like this

```
#    a b c GH:SQ:p.R172G GH:SQ:p.R172W IID:WE:G12D IID:WE:G12V
# 1  1 3 4             2             2           4           4
# 2 22 4 4             2             2           2           2
# 3  2 3 4             2             2           2           2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` to get the index of column names with `/` ('nm1'), replicate the column names in 'nm1' by using `sub/scan` to create 'nm2'.  Then, `cbind` the columns that are not 'nm1', with the replicated columns ('nm1'), change the column names with 'nm2', and if needed `order` the columns.

```
 #get the column index with grep
 nm1 <- grepl('/', names(df1))
 #used regex to rearrange the substrings in the nm1 column names
 #removed the `/` and use `scan` to split at the space delimiter
 nm2 <- scan(text=gsub('([^/]+)(.)/(.*)', '\\1\\2 \\1\\3', 
           names(df1)[nm1]), what='', quiet=TRUE)
 #cbind the columns that are not in nm1, with the replicate nm1 columns 
 df2 <- cbind(df1[!nm1], setNames(df1[rep(which(nm1), each= 2)], nm2))
 #create another index to find the starting position of nm1 columns
 nm3 <- names(df1)[1:(which(nm1)[1L]-1)] 
 #we concatenate the nm3, nm2, and the rest of the columns to match 
 #the expected output order
 df2N <- df2[c(nm3, nm2, setdiff(names(df1)[!nm1], nm3))]
 df2N 
 #   a b IID:WE:G12D IID:WE:G12V GH:SQ:p.R172W GH:SQ:p.R172G c
 #1  1 3           4           4             2             2 4
 #2 22 4           2           2             2             2 4
 #3  2 3           2           2             2             2 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(a = c(1L, 22L, 2L), b = c(3L, 4L, 3L),
`IID:WE:G12D/V` = c(4L, 
2L, 2L), `GH:SQ:p.R172W/G` = c(2L, 2L, 2L), c = c(4L, 4L, 4L)),
.Names = c("a", "b", "IID:WE:G12D/V", "GH:SQ:p.R172W/G", "c"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```